# @rpath image not Found error whiling trying to run my ios appliation

Tags: swift, xcode

While trying to run my app after successfully build. It throws up the following error

````
  Referenced from: /Users/ayodejiayankola/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/75AA7D26-1938-4C6D-A117-F969F0E0441D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D950D62D-E64D-41FB-A481-E3871776CABC/
  Reason: image not found
(lldb) ```
````

Comment: Doesn't the full error message mention a framework? If yes, did you correctly include it?

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth
  Referenced from:

Comment: You used https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS ? How did you add it to your project?

Comment: i cloned a private repo

Comment: And there was recommendation on installation? Like https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS ? You missed something there.

Comment: @l
I already have the pod folder among the list of pods in the project folder. Will u recommend i delete first and use this

pod 'AppAuth'
Then, run pod install.
Thank you

Comment: By looking at the name, I though it was this one, but if it's a private one, it might have some specifies. Why use that one? It makes sense to you, no? If you really want the one I linked, prefers the CocoaPods installation.

Comment: the framework was manually installed

Comment: solution did not work

Comment: Add "AppAuth.framework" in Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Contents.